# OSTicket - Unknown or invalid schema signature

Tags: php, mysql

I've brought this issue to the OS-Ticket community forum but haven't yet had a reply. I'm trying to install the latest version (1.7.0) and am getting the error:

Unknown or invalid schema signature (d959a00e55c75e0c903b9e37324fd25d .. 9e85d0c8f8532e3b0be38e99aba07aa1)

I've looked at the source code but am still unsure why this error is being generated. Does anyone know how I may be able to go about resolving this issue or what may be causing it? I've installed the system previously on my local machine without issue, the server i'm installing to is however Windows and so i'm wondering if there are any known things to be aware of when dealing with this system / MySQL on windows.

If I can't find a solution are there any recommended ticket support systems I could perhaps use instead?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the second part of signatures in the file-

include\upgrader\streams\core.sig

[Reference](https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/issues/511#issuecomment-320251480)

Answer (score 0):

There is a post in their forums for a workaround.

Post #5:  http://osticket.com/forums/showthread.php?t=13703

I contacted the Dev Team about the workaround around a month ago and they advised against it, telling me they were working on fixing it; and to give them 2-3 weeks.  Thus far, I have contacted them again with no response and have found no fix.

I have not heard of anyone using the fix reporting issues.  Still, comes with a "Use at your own risk" disclaimer I would say.

Comment: I was able to get my own installation working using the workaround suggested by Passion4Software here:
http://osticket.com/forums/showthread.php?t=13703&page=2